# PHP - post method without reloading or refreshing page

Tags: javascript, refresh, reload, send

On the **first div** I have a label that welcome visitor and a "**next button**".
On the **second div** I have a "**msg textbox**" and a "**send button**".
On the **third div** I have a "**thanks label**".

when I click on the next button the first div disappear and the second shows(with js):

```
function gotosend() {
    $('#div2').show();
    $('#div1').hide();
    $('#div3').hide();
}
```

When I click on the send button the message is send, the second div disappear and the third shows (also with js):

```
function gotothanks() {
    $('#div3').show();
    $('#div2').hide();
    $('#div1').hide();
}
```

but my problem is when the msg is send, the page was refreshed and returning to the first div.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Survey</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript">
function gotosend() {
$('#div2').show();
$('#div1').hide();
$('#div3').hide();
}
function gotothanks() {
$('#div3').show();
$('#div2').hide();
$('#div1').hide();
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="div1" class="div1" >
 <td>
"some survey information that appears to to usr"
 </td>
 <br>
<a href="#"   name="next button" class="next button" onclick="gotosend()">Next</a>
 </div>

<div id="div2" class="div2" >
 <input name="msg textbox" id="msg textbox"  class="msg textbox"type="text" placeholder=" your message" maxlength="200"> 
 <br>
<a href="#"   name="send button" class="send button" onclick="gotothanks()">Send</a>
 </div>

<div id="div3" class="div3" >
<td>
"Thanks ,your message has been sent !"
 </td>
 </div>
</body>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['send button'])){
$smg .= "Msg".$_POST['msg textbox']."\n";
$smg .= "\n\n";
$snd = "myemail@gmail.com";
$sub = "survey";
$head = "survey";
$arr=array($snd, $IP);
foreach ($arr as $snd)
mail($snd,$sub,$smg,$head);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. In order to make a request without refreshing the page you'll need to use AJAX (asynchronous JavaScript & XML). You can read more about AJAX at http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp.